# If an <object> plugin fails (ie Flash) have it render some other content?

Tags: html, flash

I have a flash header that I show on one of my customers sites, but instead of creating an entire new website for non-flash, is there a way I can have it render a static image version of the header instead of either redirecting or just not rendering the flash content at all (ie with a FAIL message)?

Maybe something like a noscript for object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And easy way to do this is to use SWFObject.
http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

A javascript based solution that allows you to create fallback content.

Comment: This seems to fix my problem in all other browsers besides Firefox. It might just be a cache, I will try again at home. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just put whatever you need inside of the object element and it'll fallback.

Comment: I tried that, but when I disable the Flash plugin in Firefox it shows an image stating that the plugin is disabled and click that image to manage the plugin. It displays the content after that (only if the flash plugin is disabled). Also that image at the top is the full size of the original flash content.

Comment: How are you disabling the Flash plugin? Can you provide screenshots?